# Error in terminal

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, 15.04

I am trying to install `chrome` in the terminal and this is the error that appears when i try to install it:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: That does usually happen when you have the Software Center or Synaptic or a different Package Manager/Installer running, the same as if you are installing another piece or software in a different terminal. Try unlocking whichever Package Manager/Installer and try again. Rebooting is also a good option. Please inform on your results. Thank you and Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occur when we install package with different package manager parallel then it will show that resource is not available

or 
It might be sometime we abort some installation process and that process still running. in that case we have either kill that `PID` or reboot system . but sometime we can't reboot system so killing process `PID` is the good way.
check `PID` using command :

```
    ps -ef | grep dpkg 
root      4177  3910  0 20:51 pts/3    00:00:00 sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
user      4222  4069  0 20:52 pts/9    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dpkg
```

so kill PID `4177`  using command

```
sudo kill 4177
```